# Auto-allocate CUDA devices for Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, cuda

I have multiple identical CUDA devices within one computer. I run multiple tensorflow training instances on that computer, each of them uses one and only one CUDA device. I would like to allocate one and only one CUDA device to a tensorflow instance automatically, whichever is free. I would like to do that when the tensorflow training instance is started. Currently I do it manually by checking availability and changing the code in the beginning of each tensorflow training instance:

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"
```

How can I automatically allocate the first (any) unused CUDA device to a tensorflow training instance? Meaning in the above code the `"0"` should be changed to `"1"`, `"2"` etc. in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a GPU scheduler, here is one: https://pypi.org/project/simple-gpu-scheduler/

I am assuming you are running same model with different parameters right? So the sample command could be:

```
simple_hypersearch "python3 train_dnn.py --lr {lr} --batch_size {bs}" -p lr 0.001 0.0005 0.0001 -p bs 32 64 128 | simple_gpu_scheduler --gpus 0,1,2
```